# Specialize template for types that contain typedef

Tags: c++, sfinae, type-traits

I have a template class that needs to be specialized for template parameters that contain specific typedef. So I need two definitions, one for the case it has the typedef and another for the case it does not.

My problem is that I don't see how to negate the SFINAE. I could obviously eliminate the special case for the non-special parameter, but I don't know how to eliminate the default for the special parameter.

So I tried partial specialization like this:

```
struct NormalType { };

struct SpecialType { typedef int special; };

template <typename T, typename IsSpecial = void>
struct DetectSpecial {
    void detected() { std::cout << "Not special...\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
struct DetectSpecial<T, typename T::special> {
    void detected() { std::cout << "Special!\n"; }
};
```

but the specialization does not get used ([as SSCCE on ideone](http://ideone.com/uMVj5M)).

I have also considered using [`enable_if`](http://www.boost.org/libs/utility/enable_if.html), but I don't see how to use it for well-formed vs. non-well-formed expressions rather than true/false.

What is the simplest way to define `DetectSpecial` differently for types that contain specific typedef (the value of the typedef may be anything; it's presence is important)?

Oh, I am still stuck with some C++03 compilers. I don't think anything change in SFINAE anyway.

Comment: This will not work because `T::special` is not `void`. When you instantiate `DetectSpecial<SpecialType>`, you're instantiating `DetectSpecial<SpecialType, void>`, which doesn't match `DetectSpecial<SpecialType, int>` (the partial specialization).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal change required is to insert some expression in the specialization that is dependent on `T::special` and yields `void` (to match the default argument). For example:

```
template<class T>
struct void_alias
{
    typedef void type;
};

template <typename T>
struct DetectSpecial<T, typename void_alias<typename T::special>::type> {
    void detected() { std::cout << "Special!\n"; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Following may help: (C++11) https://ideone.com/XISlZ6 (C++03) https://ideone.com/egKrcL

```
#include <cstdint>

template <typename U>
class has_special
{
private:
    template<typename T> struct dummy;
    template<typename T>
    static std::uint8_t check(dummy<typename T::special>*);
    template<typename T> static std::uint16_t check(...);
public:
    static
    constexpr bool value = sizeof(check<U>(0)) == sizeof(std::uint8_t);
};
```

Comment: Except I got warning that default template parameters for function templates are C++11 extension and I need it to work in C++03 compiler too.

Comment: @JanHudec [It works with some changes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9b3964f019b6c80)

Comment: @dyp: Clearly I have a mental block today as I didn't realize the easy trick of making a pointer to get something that can always be constructed.

Comment: @JanHudec It doesn't work if `T::special` is a reference, though. (But you can use the same trick of a `void_alias` or some other alias.)